# PowerShell Out-GridView is not displaying all of the output

Tags: powershell

I am using Out-GridView to display everything from a PS stack object I created; however, it does not display everything! As you can see in the picture, ellipses are put at the bottom where more output should be displayed. I am missing many lines.

I have tried so many things, but this is generally what I am doing.

```
$myStack | Out-GridView
```

Thank you in advance for the help!

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DW0N.png]

Comment: Is there only one property `string`? Did you try `$myStack |Select-Object -ExpandProperty string | Out-GridView`?

Comment: If you need to retain all of the other properties, you're likely going to want to use a DataTable object and pipe that to `Out-GridView`. Old post of mine - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46694015/powershell-v3-5-out-grid-view-truncated-data

Comment: Also check this https://powersnippets.com/convertto-datatable/ There was a link to it on an old SO post

Comment: @LotPings this errors out saying no string property

Comment: Your posted image contains just one property String? We don't know what `$myStack` represents. I think multiline entries are truncated at the 10th line. See this related article [social.technet.microsoft.com](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/e8d72dca-a5b2-466c-851f-00aecd0de8c2/truncated-output-wv3s-outgridview-results-is-it-avoidable?forum=winserverpowershell)